# Access to page only from Chrome extension

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome, browser

I'm working on my small Chrome extension, that loads my php page into popup (through iframe). But this extension shouldn't be accesible by anybody other, only by the users of my extension. Is there any way, how to do it? (headers, cookies, secret hash, etc.)

Comment: headers: no, can be mimicked. cookies: no, can be mimicked. secret hash: no, can be mimicked. In short: What you try to do is conceptually broken, but if you can live with a broken thing, you can do it like you suggest in your question.

Comment: And what is conceptually right?

Comment: You first need to understand that client =/= server. Then you might understand to what extend a browser add-on is not suitable for your task. As you already decided to use a browser add-on, conceptually right is to know about the shortcomings your approach has and live with it. See [Pekka's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644765/access-to-page-only-from-chrome-extension/7644816#7644816).

Answer (score 1):

There is no 100% reliable way for this.

Using a secret hash, and testing for it in the PHP script is one option:

```
www.example.com/mypage.php?key=129031349123423423904234
```

however, this is relatively easily spoofable - I could monitor the traffic, steal the secret hash, and enter it manually.

The only more secure way I can think of is using https, and POSTing the secret hash to the target page from within the extension. It's not 100% either  for someone who can disassemble and/or monitor what happens inside the  browser extension, but that is not trivial to break and probably the best you can do!

Comment: Https and POST won't help if you can monitor the requests the client send from within the client.